# App crashes hard in UnregisterAllAsync when trying to run in iOS 13 in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub, ios13

Pretty simple code works fine in iOS 12, but when working with the new previews for iOS 13, I get pretty hard crashes SIGSEGV with the following code:

```
Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
                {
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
                        return;
                    }

                    string[] tags_array = AppDelegate.notificationTags.ToArray();
                    NSSet tags = new NSSet(tags_array);
                    Console.WriteLine($"tags after unmount: {tags}");

                    Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                    {
                        if (errorCallback != null)
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback);
                    });
                });
```

There is no update for Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS in the last couple of years. It only seems to affect iOS 13.

It looks like it hits SBNotificationHubHelper signString:withKeyData:keyLength, then crashes into native code. No breakpoints are hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody did the fix for iOS native lib, if somebody could just convert to C# and update the Xamarin Azure Notification Hub iOS package, it would be awesome.

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/676#issuecomment-536899918

Comment: This was the problem and has been posted and the nuget package has been updated.

Comment: I was able (in our case) to do a null check before entering my code here with no errors, and push notifications still worked. I still plan on revisiting all of this though with the new changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It stopped working after updating XCode and deploying to iOS 13.

edit: I think it has something to do with the NSData deviceToken object that seems to be different in iOS 13 but for now I don't have a solution to translate it to a new working NSData object in C#.

link: https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/